# Jenkins hits permissions error not encountered in shell

Tags: jenkins, gcloud

I SSH in to my Jenkins machine and successfully execute a command:

```
bistenes@jenkins:~$ sudo su tomcat
$ gsutil ls gs://qs-build
gs://qs-build/jenkins-run_cfa_pipeline-47/
$
```

All good here. I try running the exact same command from a Jenkins project:

```
+ whoami
tomcat
+ gsutil ls gs://qs-build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/../share/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/gsutil.py", line 72, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/../share/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/gsutil.py", line 20, in main
    project, account = bootstrapping.GetActiveProjectAndAccount()
  File "/usr/local/share/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 217, in GetActiveProjectAndAccount
    project_name = properties.VALUES.core.project.Get(validate=False)
  File "/usr/local/share/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/googlecloudsdk/core/properties.py", line 501, in Get
    value = _GetProperty(self, _PropertiesFile.Load(), required)
  File "/usr/local/share/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/googlecloudsdk/core/properties.py", line 755, in _GetProperty
    value = callback()
  File "/usr/local/share/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/googlecloudsdk/core/properties.py", line 370, in <lambda>
    lambda: c_gce.Metadata().Project()])
  File "/usr/local/share/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/googlecloudsdk/core/credentials/gce.py", line 182, in Metadata
    _metadata_lock.lock(function=_CreateMetadata, argument=None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/mutex.py", line 44, in lock
    function(argument)
  File "/usr/local/share/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/googlecloudsdk/core/credentials/gce.py", line 181, in _CreateMetadata
    _metadata = _GCEMetadata()
  File "/usr/local/share/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/googlecloudsdk/core/credentials/gce.py", line 78, in __init__
    _CacheIsOnGCE(self.connected)
  File "/usr/local/share/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/googlecloudsdk/core/credentials/gce.py", line 189, in _CacheIsOnGCE
    config.Paths().GCECachePath()) as gcecache_file:
  File "/usr/local/share/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/files.py", line 511, in OpenForWritingPrivate
    MakeDir(full_parent_dir_path, mode=0700)
  File "/usr/local/share/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/files.py", line 44, in MakeDir
    os.makedirs(path, mode=mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/.config'
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

How is the Jenkins shell different from the shell I obtain via SSH? What difference could be causing `gcloud` to want to access `/root/.config` despite running as user `tomcat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system, Jenkins runs as user `tomcat`, but with environment variable `HOME` set to `/root`.

To make everything in Jenkins behave in a more sane way, add the following line to the top of your Jenkins scripts:

`export HOME=/home/tomcat`

**EDIT 2016/11/21:** Better: you can add that environment variable to your Jenkins global configuration, under "Manage Jenkins" → "Configure System" → "Global Properties"